# Can I use properties in an ivy.xml file to avoid repeating version numbers of dependencies?

Tags: apache, dependencies, ivy

Here's what part of my ivy.xml looks like right now:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.core" rev="3.0.2.RELEASE" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.context" rev="3.0.2.RELEASE" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.jdbc" rev="3.0.2.RELEASE" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.beans" rev="3.0.2.RELEASE" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.jms" rev="3.0.2.RELEASE" />
```

Here's what I'd like it to look like:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.core" rev="${spring.version}" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.context" rev="${spring.version}" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.jdbc" rev="${spring.version}" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.beans" rev="${spring.version}" />
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.jms" rev="${spring.version}" />
```

Is this possible? What's the syntax?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I ended up using XML entities to do the substitution. This keeps everything in the same file, which is important for my use case.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ivy-module [
    <!ENTITY spring.version "3.0.2.RELEASE">
]>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://incubator.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <info organisation="org" module="mod"/>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.core" rev="&spring.version;" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.context" rev="&spring.version;" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.jdbc" rev="&spring.version;" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.beans" rev="&spring.version;" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.jms" rev="&spring.version;" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Great use of XML entities. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 15):

Syntax is correct. All you need to do is set the ANT property somewhere.

For example

```
ant -Dspring.version=3.0.2.RELEASE
```

Another alternative is to add the property declaration into the **ivysettings.xml** file

```
<ivysettings>

    <property name="spring.version" value="3.0.2.RELEASE"/>

    <settings defaultResolver="maven2"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="maven2" m2compatible="true"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Cool! Is it possible to set the property inside of `ivy.xml`? That way all of the dependency information would be together.

Comment: Putting the property declaration in the ivy settings file achieves the same objective of keeping the dependency information together

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I went with my solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996048/can-i-use-properties-in-an-ivy-xml-file-to-avoid-repeating-version-numbers-of-dep/3091114#3091114) because I wanted to keep the version declarations in the same file.

Comment: This works great on the command line, but doesn't seem compatible with IvyIdea plugin for IntelliJ. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like the ivy plugin is not picking up the settings file. I'm not familiar with that plugin, so can't provide an authoritative suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property files as explained here: http://apache-ivy.996301.n3.nabble.com/ivyde-properties-on-ivy-xml-td7484.html

```
<properties file="${ivy.project.dir}/build.properties" />
```

insite ivysettings.xml